# Take the last match with regex using lookaround

Tags: java, regex

I can not write a proper regex expression for parsing logs. I have such a log file:

```
2023-02-20T16:59:24GMT+02:00 -> isCharging: true
2023-02-21T16:59:24GMT+02:00 -> Alarm scheduled for time: 18.02.2023 00:01:41
2023-02-22T16:59:24GMT+02:00 -> com.example.data.network.interceptor.NoConnectionInterceptor$NoConnectivityException: No network available, please check your WiFi or Data connection
    at com.example.data.network.interceptor.NoConnectionInterceptor.intercept(NoConnectionInterceptor.kt:24)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain$okhttp(RealCall.kt:201)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall$AsyncCall.run(RealCall.kt:517)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:760)

2023-02-23T16:59:24GMT+02:00 -> no internet connection
2023-02-24T16:59:24GMT+02:00 -> isCharging: true
2023-02-25T16:59:24GMT+02:00 -> com.example.data.network.interceptor.NoConnectionInterceptor$NoConnectivityException: No network available, please check your WiFi or Data connection
    at com.example.data.network.interceptor.NoConnectionInterceptor.intercept(NoConnectionInterceptor.kt:24)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain$okhttp(RealCall.kt:201)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall$AsyncCall.run(RealCall.kt:517)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:760)
```

I want to parse all the lines of this text in several parts to get the following output:

```
Timestamp: 2023-02-21T16:59:24GMT 
Offset: +02:00
Flag: ->
Body: Alarm scheduled for time: 18.02.2023 00:01:41
```

So I have written such an expression:

```
String regex = "(\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}T\\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}GMT)"
            + "(\\+\\d{2}:\\d{2}) "
            + "(-> )"
            + "([\\s\\S]+?(?=\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}T\\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}GMT))";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
        Matcher matcher = p.matcher(fileContent);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println("Timestamp: " + matcher.group(1));
            System.out.println("Offset: " + matcher.group(2));
            System.out.println("Flag: " + matcher.group(3));
            System.out.println("Body: " + matcher.group(4));
        }
```

And receive the following result:

```
Timestamp: 2023-02-20T16:59:24GMT
Offset: +02:00
Flag: -> 
Body: isCharging: true

Timestamp: 2023-02-21T16:59:24GMT
Offset: +02:00
Flag: -> 
Body: Alarm scheduled for time: 18.02.2023 00:01:41

Timestamp: 2023-02-22T16:59:24GMT
Offset: +02:00
Flag: -> 
Body: com.example.data.network.interceptor.NoConnectionInterceptor$NoConnectivityException: No network available, please check your WiFi or Data connection
    at com.example.data.network.interceptor.NoConnectionInterceptor.intercept(NoConnectionInterceptor.kt:24)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain$okhttp(RealCall.kt:201)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall$AsyncCall.run(RealCall.kt:517)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:760)

Timestamp: 2023-02-23T16:59:24GMT
Offset: +02:00
Flag: -> 
Body: no internet connection

Timestamp: 2023-02-24T16:59:24GMT
Offset: +02:00
Flag: -> 
Body: isCharging: true
```

So the problem is that my expression does not take the last element:

```
2023-02-25T16:59:24GMT+02:00 -> com.example.data.network.interceptor.NoConnectionInterceptor$NoConnectivityException: No network available, please check your WiFi or Data connection
    at com.example.data.network.interceptor.NoConnectionInterceptor.intercept(NoConnectionInterceptor.kt:24)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain$okhttp(RealCall.kt:201)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall$AsyncCall.run(RealCall.kt:517)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:760)
```

What am I doing wrong? Should I use here lookaround? What is the best way to obtain the desired result?

Comment: You could write `|$` at the end of the lookahead, see https://regex101.com/r/5A4yDO/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As commented by [TheFourthBird](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75589480/take-the-last-match-with-regex-using-lookaround#75589480:%7E:text=write%20%7C%24%20at-,the,-end%20of%20the) adding an alternation with `$` or `\z` will surely get you the desired matches but this regex with `[\s\S]+?` or a DOT with `DOTALL` mode will be very inefficient and if your log files are are huge as that case usually is then application will slow down considerably.

You may consider this far more efficient regex for your parsing:

```bash
^(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}GMT)(\+\d{2}:\d{2}) (-> )(.+(?:\R(?!\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}GMT).+)*)
```

Also note use of anchor `^` at the start to make this regex more correct so capture date-time stamp only at the start of long entry.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/hK8VRy/1)

**RegEx Changes:**

- `(`: Start capture group #4

  - `.+`: Match 1+ of any character before line break
  - `(?:`: Non-capture group start

    - `\R`: Match any kind of line break
    - `(?!\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}GMT)`: Negative lookahead to make sure we stop this match before start of next log entry
    - `.+`: Match 1+ of any character before line break
  - `)*`: Non-capture group end. Repeat this group 0 or more times
- `)`: End capture group #4